# Portable executable discrepancies

Tags: c++, windows, portable-executable

I'm looking at this image/walkthrough of the PE format: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKwgd.jpg

It seems to have some discrepancies from the official definition in WinNT.h though.

*#1:  The 'signature' field in 'PEHeader' isn't in the PE header in the official definition.  This discrepancy doesn't seem like it would make much of a difference.

*#2:  In the 'Optional Header', there's two 4-byte fields between 'AddressOfEntryPoint' and 'ImageBaseAddress' in the official documentation that are not shown in the walkthrough.  This one seems like it could make or break a file...  The walkthrough does show 'AddressOfEntryPoint' as taking 8 bytes when it should be 4 though.

Comment: Is the walkthrough for a 32-bit or 64-bit file?

Comment: Are you looking at the 32-bit or 64-bit structures in WinNT.h?

Comment: Ah thank you!!!  I didn't realize there were two.

Comment: The field name is `Signature` not `signature`, per [IMAGE_NT_HEADERS structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).